# How are XPC connections handled thread-wise?

Tags: core-data, concurrency, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch, xpc

Let's say I have an XPC service and two user-visible apps (menu bar item and main app). Both connect to the XPC service.

If both of these app components send a "create Foo" message, how are they dispatched? It's a single process after all, so do they arrive in a sequence or will multiple queues be used?

The XPC service uses Core Data, so I worry about whether I have to create a global queue or ensure thread confinement in any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you use CoreData, XPC or not, in a non-single-threaded executable you need to address threading, either through confinement, main-thread only, or private queue. Since XPC services don't have as well-defined a concept of a main thread (obviously, there is the first thread which will forever be the main thread, but practically speaking...) `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` is probably not useful. I've not seen any indication that any promises are made by XPC about the thread affinity of requests, so I generally proceed under the assumption that the XPC listener's threading management is an implementation detail over which I have no control (until execution transitions into my code). With that in mind, `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` looks like a bunch of work. So, if it were me, I'd run with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

Even if you empirically observed only one request executing at once, you would be better off assuming that's not guaranteed.

Comment: So I should put all Core Data operations on a queue I control myself to not make any assumptions about the framework. Sounds reasonable. Since private queues have globally unique IDs, this will even work with parallel XPC threads (if such a thing exists), correct?

Comment: CoreData provides this mechanism for you. Create an `NSManagedObjectContext` for your XPC service, using `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, and then use `-performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` to wrap all your interactions with CoreData.

Comment: Didn't know about that! This is great. So in my case I have to simply wrap each action the XPC service in one unit-of-work block, enqueue it, and get rid of race conditions just like that?! Looks good in code, but I can't believe that Core Data's single-thread-per-MOC limitation amounts to that much of a benefit.